# Font-family placeholder ion-input Ionic5

Tags: ionic-framework, styling, font-family

I am trying to change the font family of the `placeholder` of an `<ion-input>`. 
In [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input), there is no way to do it, since the only possible options for placeholders are `--placeholder-color`, `--placeholder-font-style`, `--placeholder-font-weight` and `--placeholder-opacity`. 
This is the HTML:

```
<ion-input required 
           type="text" 
           maxlength="30"
           placeholder="Your username">
</ion-input>
```

What I already tried without success:

```
ion-input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'My-font', sans-serif;
  --ion-font-family: 'My-font', sans-serif;
}
```

and I tried to replace the `::placeholder` with `::-webkit-input-placeholder`, `:-ms-input-placeholder`, `:-moz-placeholder`.

What I'd like to achieve:

```
ion-input {
  --placeholder-font-family: 'My-font', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: So you want the font-family of your input to be different than the font-family of your placeholder text?

Comment: @Wesley No, I want placeholders to have my custom font-family

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholder font just inherits from the input font. If your input font and placeholder font can be the same, then just apply the css style to your input element.

```css
ion-input {
  --ion-font-family: 'My-font', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: You solved my problem, thank you. But `--ion-font-family` is needed and not `font-family`